# Objective-C public get set method for private property

Tags: objective-c, properties, private, synthesize

I wonder if it is possible to use @synthesize on a private @property so that the get/set methods have public access.

Right now my code looks something like this

SomeClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
    @private
    int somePrivateVariable;
}
@end
```

SomeClass.m

```
#import "SomeClass.h"
@interface SomeClass ()
@property int somePrivateVariable;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize somePrivateVariable;
@end
```

Then in some outside function I want to be able to write:

```
#import "SomeClass.h"
SomeClass *someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
[someClass setSomePrivateVariable:1337];  // set the var
NSLog("value: %i", [someClass getSomePrivateVariable]); // get the var
```

I know that I can just create my own get/set methods in the header file but I would enjoy using the @synthesize very much more.

Comment: That public interface isn't a property. It's an old school ivar that's been marked private.

Comment: Why make it private if you want it to be public?

Comment: I am curious if it is possible, but I guess there is not much point to it..

Comment: What you are asking is totally pointless but you could do it by adding the setter/getter method declarations to the .h as public methods.

Comment: Your code is out of date. Please learn ObjC 2.0 feature (e.g. auto synthesize) and stop using whatever material that you were using to study ObjC

Comment: Ok, I googled and this is pretty much what I found. Otherwise I don't synthesize and also don't use {@private}, hopefully that is the right way

Comment: Should be "int _ somePrivateVariable" and no synthesize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a public property to mirror a private one, just override the public property's getter and setter and return the private one.

```
@interface Test : NSObject

@property NSObject *publicObject;

@end
```

Then, in the implementation:

```
@interface Test ()

@property NSObject *privateObject;

@end

@implementation Test

- (NSObject *)publicObject
{
    return self.privateObject;
}

- (void)setPublicObject:(NSObject *)publicObject
{
    self.privateObject = publicObject;
}

@end
```